# Does there exist a function for integral of $e^{-x^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, numerical-methods

I am wondering if the graph of

> $$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}{e^{-t^2}}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

is possible to be written as some function without the Error Function,
since it looks like an existing function when I try to plot it using an advanced calculator.

If this is not possible, why not?

Comment: Up to a constant, this is the error function $\operatorname{erf}$, so it's not what you call "imaginary". What is $\sin(x)$ then? Is it also "imaginary"? The functions that we usually see and work with are called "elementary". It is a very, very, very small class of functions. You could add the error function to that class, if you want. Similarly as, e.g., $\sin$ or $\cos$ it can be defined by power series.

Comment: @amsmath so if i apply tailor series thats how far ill get to some 'elementary' function?

Comment: i would even appreciate if there exists some equation that is equivalent when plotted

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Properties

Comment: The choice to regard a symbolic expression as not needing simplification is largely an aesthetic one (although various systems of choices can be formalized and result in useful mathematics). For example, given $x$, how many digits of that integral do you want? And how is that different from asking how many digits of $\pi$ (presumably a "solved" expression) that you want? If $\sin(1)$ feels like a solved problem, and that integral does not, what is the difference? These are open-ended questions with no right or wrong answers.

Comment: The fact that it cannot belong to a broad class called "elementary functions" is not easily nor briefly  proven.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral